# Foreign key, key split in two tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key

I have to record a list of events made of action, reason (optional, may be multiple), user.
I have a master table with all the valid action, and another with all the valid action-reason combination.
All tables have a unique identity (not displayed in the example).

```
master_actions
action
A1
A2
A3

master_action_reasons
action  reason
A1      NULL
A2      R1
A2      R2
A3      R1
A3      R2
A3      R3

events
action  user   id
A1      John   E1
A3      Lisa   E2
A3      Sue    E3

reasons
event reason
E2    R1 
E2    R3
E3    R2
```

Question: how do I make sure that the combination action-reason is valid, i.e. exists in master_action_reasons? Since the action is in one table, and the reason in another, I cannot use a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for CHECK constraints using a function. Step one, write a function that does something like (EDIT: Used Event instead of Action sorry!):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckReasonValid(@intReason, @intEvent)
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @NumRows int
   SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*) FROM master_action_reason mar 
       INNER JOIN Events e ON mar.Action = e.Action
       WHERE mar.Reason = @intReason AND e.Event = @Event
   RETURN @NumRows 
END;
```

Then in your table definition, add the CHECK constraint, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Reasons
ADD CONSTRAINT chkActionReasonValid CHECK (dbo.CheckReasonValid(Reason,Event) >= 1 );
```

Comment: When I insert/update an item in the table Reasons, this will work. But will it prevent from deleting an item from master_action_reason, if this would cause inconsistency, like a foreign key would?

Comment: @carlo.borreo why would you delete reasons that have been used? If you do, why wouldn't you also delete the rows in the other tables where they have been used, or update the values to null or some replacement reason?

Comment: Deleting an item in your master_action_reasons table would leave delinquent records in your Reasons table. You would need to clean up the table first where the records will become invalid.

Comment: Uh, @blobbles, I'd be ***VERY*** careful with check constraints using functions. Check out the first few articles from [this search](http://www.google.com/search?q=check+constraint+function+alex+kuznetsov)...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yep, I should have made a disclaimer - be very careful about the impact of the constraint if you are doing multi row inserts/updates carlo! They can add a LOT of overhead. The Check constraint includes ALL the Reason table columns, so theoretically it should always be checked nomatter what is updated on the Reasons table (2nd link "Be careful with constraints calling UDFs")

Comment: It's not just a performance issue - they can fail to do their job.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by the second part of my last comment. I believe (please correct me if I am wrong) the constraint can not do its job if you check something within the function that was not one of the columns given in the `CHECK` statement. In this case, all table columns are given and no other columns are used in the function, hence the function is "fully inclusive" and doesn't rely on some other outside check. So if you change anything in the table, it always fires.